# Where to store the state of ribbon controls in a Word 2010 addin

Tags: visual-studio, ms-word

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to create a Word 2010 addin with a custom ribbon.  It has various checkboxes and editboxes on it.  Where do I store the state of the checkboxes and the values in the editboxes when the document is closed?  Do a use an exiting document property and de/serialize it myself?  Or does Word have another mechanism for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use document properties, or you might consider a Custom XML Part, which is essentially an XML document containing whatever XML you like, which is included in the docx as a part.

Comment: This worked.  I used the Doc.Variables property accessible in the Application_DocumentOpen and Application_DocumentBeforeClose events. Thanks for the help.